# Изменение курсора при наведении на ссылку

Tags: delphi-7

Как сделать, что при наведении на Label1 курсор менялся на pointer, сама Label1 содержит ссылку.

Comment: В свойствах Label есть для этого настройка - "Cursor", кажется, вот ее надо указать в "Pointer". Давно в D7 не работал.

Comment: И правда, есть, спасибо за наводку!